# Form onsubmit() being ignored by Ajax form submission

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've got two javascripts, one for form validation, one for form submission. When I submit the form the "normal" way, without ajax, the form validation script runs perfectly. Now I've added the ajax form submission, the form onSubmit="validateContactForm();" is being ignored

form html

```
        <form name="frm-form" id="id-form" onsubmit="validateContactForm();">
        <input type="text" class="formbox" name="frm-name" id="id-name" placeholder="Your Name" />
        <input type="text" class="formbox" name="frm-company" id="id-company" placeholder="Company Name" />
        <input type="text" class="formbox" name="frm-email" id="id-email" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input type="text" class="formbox" name="frm-phone" id="id-phone" placeholder="Telephone Number" />
        <textarea class="textarea" name="frm-message" id="id-message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>            
        <input type="submit" name="frm-send" id="id-send" value="Send Message" class="btn-standard" />
        <div id="div-form-message"></div>    
        </form>
```

form submission script

```
$(function(){
$('#id-form').on('submit', function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    var post_url = "send-message.asp";
    var method = "POST";
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: post_url,
        type: method,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {               
            //
        },
        error: function() {
            //
        }
    });
});
});
```

form validation script

```
function validateContactForm()  
{
return true if validation is met;
return false if validation isnt met;
}
```

Both scripts work fine on there own, but dont work together.

Comment: Could be being skipped because ajax gets run first. Add async false to the ajax method and move your function call above it

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in your function and see if the function gets hit when you submit the form.

Comment: Show your validateContactForm()

Answer (score 0):

You can call your custom validator within your form submission script. That way you can still do your ajax call and validate your results.

```
$(function(){
$('#id-form').on('submit', function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validateContactForm() == true) {
      var post_url = "send-message.asp";
      var method = "POST";
      var form_data = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
          url: post_url,
          type: method,
          data: form_data,
          success: function(data) {               
              //
          },
          error: function() {
              //
          }
      });
    }
});
});
```

I suspect the `e.preventDefault()` is preventing your onsubmit handler from working. Submitting a form is considered an event.